# Finding the Cardinality defined sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm a having a bit of a struggle dealing with this following question.

[image]

Let $C\in\mathbb R$.

We define $\Delta(C)=\{x-y | x\in C, y\in C\}$.

And for $A,B \in \mathbb R$, we define $P_B(A)=\{C\subseteq A; \Delta(C)\subseteq B\}$.

Find the cardinality of the following sets:
$P_{(-1,1)}(\mathbb R)$, $P_{(-1,1)}(\mathbb Q)$, $P_{(-1,1)}(\mathbb Z)$, $P_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb R)$.

Any suggestions, hints and enlightments will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll do the easy one, the 3rd one. That's the set of all subsets $C$ of the integers such that if $x,y$ are in $C$ then $x-y$ is in the open interval $(-1,1)$. But if $x,y$ are integers, then their difference is an integer, and the only integer in $(-1,1)$ is zero. So all the elements of $C$ must be the same, so $C$ must be a one element set. So, the set you are asking about is the set of all one-element subsets of the integers, and the cardinality of that set is the same as the cardinality of the integers.